# difference between destructor and garbage collector

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, destructor

I want to know is there any difference between destructor and garbage collector, destructor is used to dispose of all unused objects at the end of the lifetime of the application, same is the use of the garbage collector, garbage collector can be manually called or done at the end of the application, same with the destructor, both are optional and use to dispose the unreferenced object, can anyone point me to whats the exact difference

Comment: .Net (like most garbage collected languages) doesn't have destructors. In C++/CLI they're faked using finalizers.

Comment: @Billy the c# language spec has used both the terms "finalizer" and "destructor" referring to the same thing.

Comment: @MarcGravell: That's strange; they really have completely different semantics. One concept is run deterministicly; the other is not. I'm thinking more at the CLR level than the C# level though; after all the question says .Net rather than C#, and as far as the CLR is concerned destructors do not exist.

Comment: @Billy indeed, and that may well be why the terminology has changed over time. But the fact remains: the terms have become a little but interchangeable as a consequence.

Comment: @MarcGravell: At least in C# circles :) (If I said that finalizers and destructors are interchangeable to a C++/CLI person I'd probably be shot)

Answer (score 7):

The garbage collector and finalizer/destructor are intrinsically linked - however, most objects do not need (and do not have) a destructor. They are actually very rare in managed code, and are usually used to ensure unmanaged resources are released. If an object has a destructor/finalizer, the garbage collector invokes it around the same time as collection (maybe in the next pass). Garbage collection is non-deterministic - it happens when it happens - often relating to memory pressure.

Far more common, however, is IDisposable. This allows a more predictable pattern for releasing resources **now** (rather than when GC next happens). Often, classes that have a finalizer will *also* be IDisposable, with the Dispose() implementation disabling the destructor (it isn't needed if we've already cleaned up). Note that Dispose() is unrelated to garbage collection, but has language support via the "using" statement.

IDisposable is **much** more common than finalizers. You are responsible for ensuring anything IDisposable gets disposed. Additional note: disposing something does not cause the object to get collected; that is done only by the GC on whatever schedule the GC chooses. Disposal, rather, release *associated resources*. As an example, you wouldn't want a file being locked open until GC happens; the Dispose() here unlocks the file (by releasing the OS file handle).

Comment: Ok, let me check whether i got the concept, GC is used to jsut check whether any disposing of the object is required, and if any it will call the destructor, GC cannot destro anything on its own, and Desctructor on the other hand, will destroy the object at the end of the class, and destructor cannot check for the memory issues, it jsut destroys everything at the end. am i right?

Comment: @Abbas multiple "not quite" I'm afraid. Firstly, avoid the term "dispose" - the GC never "disposes" in terms if `IDisposable`, so it is worth staying far away from that word. Now; the GC is responsible for reclaiming the memory on the managed heap that each object used, once each object is no longer reachable. It very much can destroy anything. However, **if** there is a destructor/finalizer (and such hasn't been explicitly disabled for that object), then the GC will invoke the destructor/finalizer to allow the class a chance to clean up any unmanaged resources.

Comment: you said " It very much can destroy anything", and also the destructor can destroy everything at the end, in that case whats the difference between  the both, however MSDN says "When the object is eligible for destruction, the garbage collector runs the Finalize method of the object.", this means GC cannot free up memory, it has to call destructor to free up memory: here the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx.

Comment: @Abbas the destructor cannot release **managed** memory - the GC handles that; the job of a finalizer/destructor in CLI is to release **unmanaged** resources - OS handles, unmanaged memory segments, things like that.

Comment: so can't GC, free up memory on heap occupied by some object, which is not referenced anywhere, and whats the difference between managed and unmanaged memory.

Comment: @Abbas: The garbage collector primarily works by copying all the objects it can find to a new part of RAM, and then nuking the old area; it neither knows nor cares whether there were five or 500,000 objects left behind.  Objects with finalizers are a special case (there are a few others as well).  Just before nuking the old area, the GC checks all of the objects that have registered for finalization to see if any of them haven't been brought over yet.  If any are left behind, they're added to a list of objects eligible for *immediate* finalization, and...

Comment: ...removed from the list of objects registered for finalization.  In addition, they *and any objects to which they hold references* will be moved to the new area before the old area is nuked.

Answer (score 6):

The destructor is a special member function which is invoked when an object is destroyed. It is the last method run by a class.

The garbage collector is part of the framework, automatically manages memory, and non-deterministically collects unreferenced objects to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: The `Finalize` method generated by the destructor is invoked when the GC discovers an object that, <i>but for the fact that the object was registered for finalization</i>, would no longer exist.  It is often the last method run on a class object, but it's possible that a rooted strong reference to the object might get created and stored somewhere any time before the finalizer completes (and possibly before it even starts!) in which case the object might continue to exist indefinitely.

Answer (score 3):

The garbage collector is a part of the .NET environment that keeps track of objects and makes sure that objects are removed from memory when they are no longer needed.

A destructor is a part of a class design. It's the opposite of a constructor. When you declare it the GC will call it when it destroys an object.

[Here is the MSDN documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector primarily works by copying all the objects it can find to a new part of RAM, and then nuking the old area; it neither knows nor cares whether there were five or 500,000 objects left behind.  Note that in addition to finding all objects referred to by live strong references, the garbage collector can find a few other objects as well, including objects which override `Finalize`, objects used as monitor locks, objects targeted by WeakReference objects, etc.  Before nuking the old area from orbit, the garbage collector must deal with any of 'special' objects it knows about that might still be sitting there.

Among other things, the garbage collector has a list of all objects that have registered a finalizer; it will checks all objects on that list to see if they've yet been copied to the new memory area.  If any are found that haven't been, they'll be removed from the list of objects with a registered finalizer and added to a list of objects whose `Finalize` method should be run as soon as practical.  Once this has been done for all objects with a registered finalizer, any objects on the list of objects needing immediate finalization, as well as any object to which those objects holds a reference, will be copied to the new area.